# How to display shopify free them output on my laptop using visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, shopify

I downloded a shopify free theme and want to make little bit changes.Already installed visual studio code.
guide me how can i display them output using this visual studio code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Shopify Theme Kit](https://shopify.github.io/themekit/) - a CLI tool that allows you to work with your theme files on your local machine using any preferred IDE or text editor.

Comment: Thanks, i got it